# Sidekiq-Unique-jobs Lock works only for first Worker, then all pending jobs get executed at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I could have 3 jobs pending in the queue, as soon as the first Job is done, all remaining workers get executed at the same time. Why is that? I want each worker to get a lock and make the other jobs wait, in a serialized-fashion.

```
class StuffWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options lock: :until_executed,
                  lock_timeout: 999,
                  lock_info: true,
                  lock_args_method: :lock_args

  def self.lock_args(args)
    [args[0], args[1]]
  end

  def perform(company_id, person_id)
    sleep 10
    logger.info "STARTING IT! at #{DateTime.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}"
  end
end
```

Produces the following:

```
JID-ce8c692b5341adb7a24584ab INFO: STARTING IT! at 23:29:52
JID-ce8c692b5341adb7a24584ab INFO: done: 10.728 sec
JID-ca8dac1cbd7cbaf5d87f6096 INFO: STARTING IT! at 23:30:02
JID-463bfe792775e1412d3c0af7 INFO: STARTING IT! at 23:30:02
JID-463bfe792775e1412d3c0af7 INFO: done: 17.754 sec
JID-ca8dac1cbd7cbaf5d87f6096 INFO: done: 14.024 sec
```

Comment: Does these tasks share same `company_id` and `person_id`? Could you print it out?

Comment: Yes; they all have the same company id and person id; the worker itself is aggregating data; so a race condition happens when more workers are queued and executed at once

Answer (score 0):

Possible, what you want is a runtime lock only, not queue lock. You have to use `while_executing` lock type https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs#while-executing.